# How to set layout in java GUI swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am trying to create a register form for my application(school project), I wanted to set the layout to `BoxLayout` but the `Jtextfields` and combo box is having issue as you can see below, does this issue relates to `setSize()` or is it something I am doing incorrect,I just want the `Jtextfields` sorts vertically , I appreciate the support
[image]

```
private JPanel SetUpRegister() {
        JLabel registerLabel = new JLabel("Registera");

        registerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        loginRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        passwordRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        fnRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        lnRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        ageRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        String[] genderlist = new String[] { "Male", "Female", "Other" };
        JComboBox<String> registerList = new JComboBox<>(genderlist);

        JPanel registerPanel = new JPanel();    
        registerPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 140, 0));
        registerPanel.add(registerLabel);
        registerPanel.add(loginRegisterInput);
        registerPanel.add(passwordRegisterInput);
        registerPanel.add(fnRegisterInput);
        registerPanel.add(lnRegisterInput);
        registerPanel.add(ageRegisterInput);
        registerPanel.add(registerList);
        registerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(registerPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        return registerPanel;

}
```

Comment: Set the layout before you add the components - you might find that improves your chances

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did it before, unfortunately nothing was resolved

Comment: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) `new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30)` better to use `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 30)` as Arial is likely to be missing from OS X & they would prefer Helvetica in any case.

Comment: "_Jtextfields and combo box is having issue as you can see below_"  **what** is the issue ?

Comment: @c0der The input fields are huge

Answer (score 1):

> The input fields are huge

The `BoxLayout` will attempt to resize components when extra space is available on the panel. It will resize a component up to its maximum size.

For some reason the maximum height of a `JTextField` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which makes no sense to me, since the height of the text never changes as you enter more text.

In any case you have a couple of choices:

1. Use a different layout manager, like the `GridBagLayout`. The `GridBagLayout`, will respect the preferred size of the text fields.
2. Create a custom `JTestField` and override the `getMaximumSize()` method to return the preferred height of the component
3. Use a wrapper panel.

For the wrapper panel you could do:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(registerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
return wrapper;
//return registerPanel;
```

The BorderLayout will respect the preferred height of any component added to the PAGE_START, so there is no need for the BoxLayout to resize any component.

Answer (score 0):

```
private JPanel SetUpRegister() {
    JLabel registerLabel = new JLabel("Registera");
    JLabel registerLabel1 = new JLabel("Login :");
    JLabel registerLabel2 = new JLabel("Password :");
    JLabel registerLabel3 = new JLabel("First Name :");
    JLabel registerLabel4 = new JLabel("Last Name :");
    JLabel registerLabel5 = new JLabel("Age :");
    JLabel registerLabel6 = new JLabel("Gender :");
    JLabel registerLabel7 = new JLabel("Bio :");
    registerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
    JButton createAccButton = new JButton("Create");
    createAccButton.addActionListener(new CreateAccountListener());
    loginRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
    passwordRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
    fnRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
    lnRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
    ageRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
    bioRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);

    String[] genderlist = new String[] { "Male", "Female", "Other" };
    registerList = new JComboBox(genderlist);
    JPanel registerPanel = new JPanel();
    registerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(registerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    registerPanel.add(registerLabel);

    JPanel registerLabPanel = new JPanel();
    registerLabPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    registerLabPanel.add(registerLabel);

    JPanel usernamePanel = new JPanel();
    usernamePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    usernamePanel.add(registerLabel1);
    usernamePanel.add(loginRegisterInput);

    JPanel passwordPanel = new JPanel();
    passwordPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    passwordPanel.add(registerLabel2);
    passwordPanel.add(passwordRegisterInput);

    JPanel fnPanel = new JPanel();
    fnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fnPanel.add(registerLabel3);
    fnPanel.add(fnRegisterInput);

    JPanel lnPanel = new JPanel();
    lnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    lnPanel.add(registerLabel4);
    lnPanel.add(lnRegisterInput);

    JPanel agePanel = new JPanel();
    agePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    agePanel.add(registerLabel5);
    agePanel.add(ageRegisterInput);

    JPanel genderPanel = new JPanel();
    genderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    genderPanel.add(registerLabel6);
    genderPanel.add(registerList);

    JPanel bioPanel = new JPanel();
    bioPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    bioPanel.add(registerLabel7);
    bioPanel.add(bioRegisterInput);

    JPanel buttonLoginPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonLoginPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonLoginPanel.add(createAccButton);

    registerPanel.add(registerLabel);
    registerPanel.add(usernamePanel);
    registerPanel.add(passwordPanel);
    registerPanel.add(fnPanel);
    registerPanel.add(lnPanel);
    registerPanel.add(agePanel);
    registerPanel.add(genderPanel);
    registerPanel.add(bioPanel);
    registerPanel.add(buttonLoginPanel);

    return registerPanel;

}
```

I fixed the issue by making a Panel for each input and label